# Unable to Parse encoded Text in XML through Jquery .text()

Tags: jquery, xml, text

I am unable to parse this XML text which is in form of encoded one.
Can you please help me in extracting it
.text() is not working.

XMl is as below

```
<link-code-html>&lt;a href="11496944"&gt;Rado Women's Florence Watch
Model: R48800713
Retail: $3,900
Special: $1,149 + Free Shipping
Coupon Code: AFFFLORE1149
Expires: 10/8 at 11:59 pm
&lt;/a&gt;&lt;img src="11496944" width="1" height="1" border="0"/&gt;</link-code-html>
```

Comment: my sample XML is in this URL http://dealscounty.com/xml/cjURL.xml

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.parseXML()`:

*jQuery.parseXML uses the native parsing function of the browser to create a valid XML Document. This document can then be passed to jQuery to create a typical jQuery object that can be traversed and manipulated.*

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: I have Used the same, parseXML first and then for each node I did   var urlStr=   ($(this).find("link-code-html").text());  This is not working earlier I have used  parse successfully for String which are not in encoded formats. For this  case it is not extracting.

Comment: Have you tried `$(this).find("link-code-html").html().text()`?

Comment: it doesn't work with html().text()  Please find the Sample Html URL for this and see my code, you can see through view source http://dealscounty.com/xml/cjURL.html

Comment: The whole Javascript stuff is messed up. Errors on the console, the jQuery library being added way too late on the page (stick it to the headers)... Fix all of this, then much probably your XML bits will just work.